# Grease Pencil not drawing on a flat plane

Tags: grease-pencil

I am animating over a mesh plane background with an image. I do the camera move first then draw the figure from the camera view or front view. when I do this the grease pencil plane has a 'curve' to it so by the time I get to the end of the camera move the pencil layer is curved all the way behind the mesh.

any ideas on why I am seeing this behaviour?

thanks!

[image]

Comment: I wonder if it is following the curve of the camera. Maybe as you are drawing in camera view, it is drawing a constant distance from the camera.

Comment: It’s interesting because the camera isn’t rotating it’s always pointing straight but there is a light curve to the move. I’ll check it out.